# "javadoc" in C#

Tags: c#, documentation, javadoc

I have been looking online to find out how to "javadoc" in C# console application. All the articles refer to a webform of C# in the case for that, `///` would be the javadoc. What is the way to do it if you are making a console application in visual studio?

Edit:
I remember it had to deal with a `@` before the method

Comment: Put three forward-slashes and you'll see VS autogenerating the rest for you.

Comment: [Jetbrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) also autogenerates this after putting three forward-slashes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Three forward slashes begins the doc:

```
/// <summary>
/// My method does stuff.
/// </summary>
public void MyMethod() { ... }
```

Then, you can modify the project properties to output XML files that contain the documentation for other developers, or use an application like **[SandCastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB)** to generate full-fledged documentation web pages.